# if I have some function in __init__.py how to imported this function into current directory code

Tags: python, python-import, init, python-packaging

I use python 3.6:

my directory is like:

```
mypackage
--__init__.py
--manage.py
```

In my **init**.py I have function:

```
def create_app(config_object=DefaultConfig):
    ...
```

In my manage.py I have function:

```
from . import create_app
app=create_app()
```

I met the error:

```
    from . import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app
```

If I directly use create_app function, I will meet error:

```
NameError: name 'create_app' is not defined
```

How to import the funtions write in **init**.py?

Comment: Why are you importing *from* `__init__.py`? Move the function into manage then import it **to** init.

Comment: `__init__.py` is not a good place for functions that are imported elsewhere. It exists to run code that initializes the package on the first import. In most cased there is very few code inside, some convenience imports maybe.

Comment: In your `manage.py` file, Try `import mypackage` then use `mypackage.create_app()` to invoke the `create_app` method defined in the `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to invoke `manage.py` as a module in the package `mypackage`.

```
python -m mypackage.manage # python 2.x
```

or

```
python3 -m mypackage.manage # python 3.x
```

Now, import the function to `manage.py` as:

```
from mypackage import create_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
from mypackage.manage import create_app
```

Tested on python 3.5 windows 7.